# Possible to restrict children access to features within app?

Tags: ios

I'm just wondering if there is some API in iOS that would let me do the following:

```
if (parental controls have been set)
{
    disable feature
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no API access to restrictions and parental controls however you can set the app age rating so parental control will not allow the app to be downloaded